# how to reshape an array of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I need to reshape numpy arrays in order to plot some data.
The following work fine:

```
import numpy as np
target_shape = (350, 277)
arbitrary_array = np.random.normal(size = 96950)
reshaped_array = np.reshape(arbitrary_array, target_shape)
```

However, if instead of an array of shape (96950, ) I have an array of tuples with 3 elements each (96950,3) I got a

```
cannot reshape array of size 290850 into shape (350,277)
```

Here the code to replicate the error

```
array_of_tuple = np.array([(el, el, el) for el in arbitrary_array])
reshaped_array = np.reshape(array_of_tuple, target_shape)
```

I guess that what reshape is doing is flattening the tuples array (hence the size 290850) and then trying to reshape it. However, what I would like to have is an array of tuples in the shape (350, 277), basically ignoring the second dimension and just reshaping the tuples as they were scalar. Is there a way of achieving this ?

Comment: Have you tried `reshape` with shape `(350, 277, 3)`?

Comment: reshape to (350, 277, 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reshape to `(350, 277, 3)` instead:

```
>>> a = np.array([(x,x,x) for x in range(10)])
>>> a.reshape((2,5,3))
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8],
        [9, 9, 9]]])
```

Technically, the result will not be a 350x277 2D-array of 3-tuples but a 350x277x3 3D-array, though, but neither is your `array_of_tuple` an actual "array-of-tuples" but a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

```
reshaped_array=np.reshape(array_of_tuple,(350,-1))
reshaped_array.shape
```

gives (350, 831)

You are getting the error because of the mismatch of column numbers and rows number that cover the entire elements of array

```
350*831= 290850   where as
350*277=96950
```

and hence numpy doesnt know what to do with the additional elements of the array,,You can try reducing the original size of the array to reduce the number of elements.If you dont want to remove the elements then

```
reshape(350,277,3)
```

is an option

Answer (score 1):

Your problem steps from a misconception of the result of  `np.array(iterable)`, have a look at this

```
In [7]: import numpy as np

In [8]: np.array([(el, el, el) for el in (1,)])
Out[8]: array([[1, 1, 1]])

In [9]: _.shape
Out[9]: (1, 3)
```

and ask yourself which is the shape of

```
array_of_tuple = np.array([(el, el, el) for el in np.random.normal(size = 96950)])
```